# Custom annotation for file validation not working: Spring 3.1.2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-annotations

I recently updated my application to Spring 3.1.2 and I created a custom annotation which is not getting triggerred when applied on Method. Below is the code for the same.

The annotation.

```java
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
@Constraint(validatedBy = AllowedFileValidator.class)
public @interface AllowedFiles {
  String message() default "Invalid File Type";
  Class<?>[] groups() default {};
  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
  String [] allowedTypes();
}
```

The validator class.

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class AllowedFileValidator implements ConstraintValidator<AllowedFiles, MultipartFile> {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AllowedFileValidator.class);
    
  private List<String> allowedFileTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    
  @Override
  public void initialize(AllowedFiles constraintAnnotation) {
    allowedFileTypes = Arrays.asList(constraintAnnotation.allowedTypes());
  }

  @Override
  //@Around("@annotation(AllowedFiles)")
  public boolean isValid(MultipartFile value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    LOGGER.debug("Inside Isvalid method");
    boolean flag = false;
    if(allowedFileTypes.contains(value.getContentType())) {
      LOGGER.debug("File type is valid");
      flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
  }
}
```

The method that it is applied on.

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/createFile", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@AllowedFiles(
  allowedTypes = {
    "application/x-zip-compressed", "text/csv", "image/bmp", "text/plain", 
    "image/png","image/jpeg", "application/pdf", "application/zip",
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
  }
)
public ResponseEntity<ClassName> createFile(
  @Valid @RequestPart("payload") String input,
  @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile[] file
) {
  // Do something
}
```

Is there something wrong with the annotation created? If so please let me know. If not, what can be done to resolve this issue?

Note: I have added necessary dependencies in pom.xml few of them are:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- Aspect J added for annotation -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- Aspect J added for annotation -->
```

Comment: try to place your `@AllowedFiles` annotation before `MultipartFile[] file` argument in method instead of the method itself, and add `@Validated` annotation to your controller to allow method-level validation

Comment: Your code looks like you cannot quite decide if you want to use an aspect or a validator.